# How to find derivative of squared Frobenius Norm of XX transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

Can anyone show me how to get the derivative of the squared Frobenius Norm for this second degree matrix $X$?

$$||XX^T||_F^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a colon to denote the matrix inner product.

Write down the function and calculate its gradient as follows
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \big\|XX^T\big\|_F^2 \\
  &= XX^T:XX^T \\
d\phi
  &= 2XX^T:d(XX^T) \\
  &= 2XX^T:\Big(X\,dX^T+dX\,X^T\Big) \\
  &= 2\Big(XX^T+(XX^T)^T\Big):dX\,X^T \\
  &= 4XX^TX:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
  &= 4XX^TX \\
}$$
This is analogous to the scalar $({\tt1}\times{\tt1})$ derivative result
$$\frac{d X^4}{dX}=4X^3$$